# How to check if a user is already registered in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication for application registration. If someone who registered for the application wants to register again, I want to give a warning that this mail is being used, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Which platform do you implement ... and firebase has various platform samples with all the features. The firebase GitHub page is [here](https://github.com/firebase) .it's hard to find you needed one try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples)

Comment: I am coding java with android studio

Comment: chek this it's have java & kotlin demos https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a given email address is already registered in Firebase, you can call the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)).

The flow for this is typically that:

1. You ask/determine the email address of the user.
2. You call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` to see if there's any provider for the email address.
3. You show a page where the user can pick from the methods that you got back in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() doesn't work for me. It sends empty list. You can use createUserWithEmailAndPassword(). If this methos returns error `The email address is already in use by another account.` it means user has registration